# The async method is not awaited

Tags: c#, async-await

I have this three methods:

```
Public myConstructor()
        {
            myMethodAsync02();

            string myDummy = "";
        }


        private async void myMethodAsync02()
        {
            await myMethodAsync();
        }


        private async Task myMethodAsync()
        {
            await Task.Delay(5000);


            string myDummy = "";
        }
```

When I click the button, the line with the myDummy string is reached before myMethod() is finished.

I would like to know how I could wait until the async method finishes after the 5 seconds.

I know that myMethodAsync02 should return a task, but this is a simplify example of my real case, because in my real case the yMethodAsync02 method is an event handler method, so it has to returns a void type.

Thanks.

Comment: You have async void. That's a very bad idea. Don't do it, unless it's an event handler. See [Async Await Best Practices](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx). You need to await your call to `myMethodAsync02`. Which means it need to return a Task.

Comment: @mason it is allowable *for the event handler*, as per Steve's answer; beyond that: Task and await

Comment: MyMethod02 is an event handler, so the unique option is to return void.

Comment: @MarcGravell Yes, I did include the disclaimer "unless it's an event handler".

Comment: @mason apparently I fail at reading today :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    await myMethodAsync02();

    string myDummy = "";
}

private Task myMethodAsync02()
{
     return myMethodAsync();
}
```

just make your event async and await on it.

Comment: Well, in this case the click event method can be async, but in my real case is the constructor, so it can't be async.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGarcía constructor should NOT call any async method. You should make another async initialize method and use a factory style method to generate your object

Comment: @ÁlvaroGarcía Your original question showed it being called from an event handler, not a constructor. It's not very fair to change the question like that after someone has answered.

Answer (score 1):

Because your `myMethodAsync02();` is an `async void` and not awaited (nor can be in this case) therefore it executes immediately and the execution of click event body continues straight to `string myDummy = "";`

In your case you dont need `myMethodAsync02();`, just `await myMethodAsync()`.